# My Second to Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds calculator has couple issues

Tags: python, while-loop, except

So I am Trying to make a calculator that can show how much days, hours, minutes, and seconds the input seconds are. And I wanted to hide the  0s in eg)**0 days, 0 hours,** 2 minutes, 23 seconds
I could get them done, but there are two big problems...

1. whenever I input numbers like 3600, ir 60, the program just returns to start without any messages..
2. Whenever I try to remove xx**.0**, and add :.0f to the {}s, I get ValueErrors...

Im pretty much a beginner and honestly I tried for a whole day but Im still struggling... would appreciate it if you can tell me whats wrong..

```
while 1:
try:
    totsec=float(input("Type desired seconds : "))#Input seconds
    if(totsec%1!=0):#Bact to input if input is not decimal
        print("Can't calculate miliseconds...")
        continue
    if(totsec<0):#Bact to input if it is negative number
        print("Negative seconds...")
        continue
    if(totsec==0):#Back to input if it's 0
        print("umm... 0 second.")
        continue
    day=totsec//86400
    hour=(totsec-86400*day)//3600
    min=(totsec-86400*day-3600*hour)//60
    sec=totsec-86400*day-3600*hour-min*60
    #
    dayout,hourout,minout,secout=f'{day}Day, ',f'{hour}Hour, ',f'{min}Minute, ',f'{sec}second'
    if(day==0):#So I don't see 0 day
        dayout=str()
    if(hour==0):
        hourout=str()
    if(min==0):
        minout=str()
    if(sec==0):
        secout=str()
    else:
        print(f'{dayout}{hourout}{minout}{secout}!')
    continue
except ValueError:
    print("Its not a number...")#if input isn't a float number
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `print(f'{dayout}{hourout}{minout}{secout}!')` command in the body of an `else` statement! Just remove the `else` statement and use the `print` command no matter what.